# sessionTokenRequirment lifetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, token

When you set the lifetime attribute of

```
<sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="00:10" />
```

Does that mean the token will expire in 10 minutes if there is no activity (no POST OR GET,etc) I am wondering if the user makes a post or get does it reset it back to 10 minutes. What I want is for the user to be logged in as long as they are actively using the app which should hit the server every minute or so. If they they stop using the app, I automatically log them out, but what I don't want is if they use the app for 11 minutes their claims have been removed. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Is it like the session timeout which times out if the user remains idle? If not is there something like that? Or am I using it in the wrong way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015996/is-sessionsecuritytoken-lifetime-the-same-as-sessiontokenrequirement-lifetime

Comment: thanks for the link I will check that out. Once I have my coffee perhaps it will all click..